# Why Magento2 uses Store Manager outside of Presentation layer?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

As per [Technical Guidelines](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/coding-standards/technical-guidelines.html)

6.2.2. Request, Response, Session, Store Manager and Cookie objects MUST be used only in the Presentation layer.

But if we check here in this file path **Store Manager** is declared

`vendor/magento/module-translation/Model/Source/InitialTranslationSource.php`

Which belongs to a domain layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you're expecting a technical answer but it may come down to the fact Magento often don't follow their own best practices, XSS prevention is a good example as a lot of strings still use `escapeNotVerified` and haven't been escaped despite their documentation stating:

> To combat this developers, must validate any value coming in from requests.

---

> /_ @escapeNotVerified _/ before output. Output escaping is not checked and should be verified. Test is green.